# How to make each array's string elements' first character to be in upper case and the remaining characters in lower case?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

This is about the title case algorithm which I extended further. I need the most efficient implementation in JavaScript. It should be extensible and scalable.

For example, I have a random array such as:

```
var arr = ["hell o", "3are", "you a","modern","332developer"];
```

If the element contents start with a number then it should ignore that index and move to the next index until it finds an initial letter and convert it to upper case. The remaining letters in the word should be in lower case. If there is space after a word in the content then it should consider that a new word and apply the same logic of applying upper case to that letter.

The results should be as below:

```
var arr = ["Hell O", "3Are", "You A","Modern","332Developer"];
```

Comment: You can find a solution for a single string here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript

Comment: and you just need to run a loop on array elements to transform all of them, or just use `forEach` on array

Comment: @eddyP23 the linked solution wouldn't work for `'3are'` (in the example it should become `'3Are'` with a capital 'A')

Comment: its about array not about strings, string are immutables but arrays are mutables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```js
var arr = ["hell o", "3are", "you a","modern","332developer"];

arr = arr.map(e => e.replace(/([^\d\s])([^\s]+)?/g, (a, b, c) => {
    let ret = b.toUpperCase();
    if(c) ret += c.toLowerCase();
    return ret;
}));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This is a nice ES6 implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Create a regex that will capture groups of characters.
- Loop over array and capture these groups.
- Replace/return title case value.

```js
var arr = ["hell o", "3are", "you a","modern","332developer"];
var result = arr.map(function(s){
  return s.replace(/([a-z]+)/gi, function(match){
    return match[0].toUpperCase() + match.substring(1);
  })
});
console.log(result)
```